# PHP Mysqli 'dynamically' saying what connection (variable) should be used

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-connection

What is the best way to use multiple (dynamic) PHP Mysqli connections?

Currently I have a single MySQL server. All my data is on this server in a few databases. But in the not too distant future my storage needs will be larger than this server can handle. So what I will probably have to do is place some databases on one server and some on another. And in the further future probably more servers will come into play.

In an effort of 'future proving' my scripts I thought that a class to point to the right server might be the best solution. I just send a 'key' of the data I want to get and it says what connection I should be using because it is stored on that server. For instance if I want to get some logs I send the key 'logs' and the class says I will need to use the predefined connection 'connection_A'.

The class currently looks something like:

```
Class DatabaseConnection {
    public $connection_name;

    function __construct($key){
        if($key=='logs'){
            $connection_name = 'connection_A';
        }
        elseif($key=='userdetails'){
            $connection_name = 'connection_B';
        }
    }
}
```

So what I do now is:

```
$connection_A = new mysqli($dbhosta, $dbusera, $dbpassa, $dbnamea);
$connection_B = new mysqli($dbhostb, $dbuserb, $dbpassb, $dbnameb);

$databaseConnection = new DatabaseConnection('logs');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `something` WHERE `timestamp`>='12378912798'";
$result = ${$databaseConnection->connection_name}->query($sql);
```

This works fine. Although it isn't as 'dynamic' as I wish it was. I mainly run into problems when functions are concerned. But that required me to do:

```
function something(){
    global $connection_A, $connection_B;

    $databaseConnection = new DatabaseConnection('logs');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `something` WHERE `timestamp`>='12378912798'";
    $result = ${$databaseConnection->connection_name}->query($sql);
}
```

OR

```
function something(){
    $databaseConnection = new DatabaseConnection('logs');
    global ${$databaseConnection->connection};

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `something` WHERE `timestamp`>='12378912798'";
    $result = ${$databaseConnection->connection_name}->query($sql);
}
```

Neither are very elegant and the first one is quite some work if I add more connections or shuffle things around.

So I thought about doing something like this:

```
Class DatabaseConnection {
    public $connection_name;

    function __construct($key){
        if($key=='logs'){
            $connection_name = 'connection_A';
        }
        elseif($key=='userdetails'){
            $connection_name = 'connection_B';
        }
    }

    function connection(){
        $this->{$this->connection_name}();
    }

    function connection_A(){
        $connection_A = new mysqli($dbhosta, $dbusera, $dbpassa, $dbnamea);
        return $connection_A;
    }

    function connection_B(){
        $connection_B = new mysqli($dbhostb, $dbuserb, $dbpassb, $dbnameb);
        return $connection_B;
    }
}
```

And using it like:

```
$databaseConnection = new DatabaseConnection('logs');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `something` WHERE `timestamp`>='12378912798'";
$result = $databaseConnection->connection->query($sql);
```

But there are functions in certain scripts that are run a few hundred times each time the script runs. (Inserts and stuff). So wouldn't this open 300 connections or something like that?

My knowledge of Mysqli is too limited to fully the consequences of this approach. I read somewhere that Mysqli pools connections together so if a scripts runs a function for the first time it uses a set of credentials to login to server_A, and it tries to do it again in the same script a few moments later, it doesn't actually creates a new connection but uses the same one. Am I right or mixing things up?

What do you think is the best way to address my need of 'dynamically' saying what server should be contacted for what sort of data? Or do you have another good idea?

Comment: Ideally your database scaling issues would remain a system issue, and not involve any coding. If you have the option look into something like Amazon's RDS to move your scalability back to a sys admin's concern. Also reconsider if all your data needs to be in a relational DB. Maybe CouchDB or Mongo would scale better for things like logs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use tools like http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd-ms.php

That allow for masters and read slaves. The other option is to look at something like amazon RDS like the other answer suggests.